# How to determine an Image is rotated less than 90 degrees using PDFBOX

Tags: java, validation, pdf, pdfbox

Hi I want to check the following scenario in PDFBOx:
"Image is rotated over an angle that is not a multiple of 90 degrees".
Can anybody please help in this topic.
Sample PDF location:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzaBYVk1XnP_UkJjMDRBc2owd0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: boolean mutipleof90 = (angle % 90 == 0);

Comment: Inspect the page content stream. You'll find `q  325.79257 -42.55899 30.90112 236.55064 164.64209 365.19037 cm  /X1 Do  Q`. Decompose that transformation matrix into its translation, scaling, rotating, and skewing parts. Look at the rotation matrix.

Comment: Hi,Could you please tell how to derive angle of rotation for PDXObjectImage object?

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari take a vector, apply the transformation matrix, and calculate the angle between the original and the transformed vector. If skewing is involved, your choice of start vector influences the result and should be normalized to best fit your needs.

Comment: Dear MKL,The PDFBox API which gets the Current Transformation Matrix (which contains the translation, rotation, scale and skew components of a transformation) is PDGraphicsState.getCurrentTransformationMatrix().
 
This returns org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix.  This contains methods for extracting the scaling and translation matrices, but strangely, it does not contain any method to get the rotation matrix.  We need a way to get the rotation matrix of the image, and from that extract the rotation angle with respect to the default co-ordinate system .Any help or suggestion on this?

Comment: As mentioned in my comment before, *the rotation* may not be well defined if skewing is involved in the current transformation Matrix. How do you wish to normalize?

Comment: Hi MKL,Could you please help me on that issue..

Comment: Downvoter can you please put your comment?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Slippery said, i have made it lengthy

```
//set the angle of the image
double angle;
if(angle % 90 == 0){
//Perform operation when the angle is multiple of 90
}else{
//Perform operation when the angle is NOT multiple of 90
}
```

This is how you can handle this scenario

Comment: How do you determine the angle of the PDXObjectImage?

Comment: The key in question is to determine rotation angle of image in PDF.